# How to set the color of the notification bar where tabs have been used?

Tags: android

The color of my notification bar remains WHITE, i want to set it to BLACK but am unable to do it.

Here is the style.xml file

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/navigationBarColor</item>

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nitesh.alexa">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.nitesh.alexa;

import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{
    JoyStickView joyStickView;


    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;


    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Initializing the tablayout
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Manual"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Status"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Database"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);



        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }


}
```

Please suggest me the ways via which i can change the backgroundcolor.

Comment: Terms like "NotificationBar", "ActionBar" and "Toolbar" are often used incorrectly/mismatched. Can you please post a screenshot with the exact bar marked, that you want to set to black? Then it's easier to guide you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> To set a custom color for the status bar, use the android:statusBarColor attribute when you extend the material theme. By default, android:statusBarColor inherits the value of android:colorPrimaryDark.

Follow one of these steps

**Step - 1 :**

Open colors.xml and change the `navigationBarColor` to `#000000`

**Step - 2 :**

Open colors.xml and change the value of `colorPrimaryDark` to `#000000`

and remove `android:statusBarColor` item in your theme.

For more info on customizing the status bar, take a look at the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar)

Comment: @NiteshSingh Check my edit. That didn't work because you're adding `android:statusBarColor` in your theme. What is the color `navigationBarColor` is referring to in the colors.xml?